# Problem: Ubuntu 18.04 greeter will not display more than 50 users

Tags: unity, login, lightdm, login-screen

How can I make all my usernames show up in the greeter in Ubuntu 18.04 (desktop)? I've tried various different greeters including

```
unity-greeter
kylin-greeter
lightdm-gtk-greeter
lightdm-kde-greeter
```

and played with various settings, but try as I might I cannot get more than 50 users to show up in the greeter. I need all my users to show up in the greeter.

I used the greeter in Ubuntu 14 with over 100 users, no problem. I need to be able to rapidly choose from over 100 logins from the greeter screen. If a hard limit has been introduced, does anybody know where I can reconfigure it, or failing that, where to change ot in the source?

Comment: There might indeed be a maximum of users that can be displayed. Not sure if you find it practical to select a user name from a list of 50+ entries. I suggest you instead enable manual login, where users log in by providing both their login and password. Apart from being more practical, this will increase security.

Comment: I used the greeter in ubuntu 14 with over 100 users, no problem. I need to be able to rapidly choose from over 100 logins from the greeter screen. If a hard limit has been introduced, does anybody know where I can reconfigure it, or failing that, where to change ot in the source ?

Comment: Perhaps edit the title of your question to indicate that this refers to a problem of displaying more than 50 users: this will put a better focus on the actual issue.